# Visual Studio 2022 - Nesting partial classes (files)

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I noticed that, in my solution, nesting partial classes is only working for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project.
For the rest of the projects (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) it is not working.
Does anyone know anything about this?

---

**Edit**: I posted the SDK because I think that is the reason. I created a new solution, Console App (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) and tried creating partial classes, still doesn't nest the files.

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit 2**
After adding the following to the `.csproj` file, it is now nested.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update=".\Services\CatalogService.*.cs">
        <DependentUpon>.\Services\CatalogService.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Though, the question still remains...

Comment: It does work for Microsoft.NET.Sdk as well, demonstrated in a Winforms project.  Fairly magical, looks like it is hardcoded to me, driven by the content of the project.csproj.user file.  Odds you can get it to work for a console mode app ought to be zilch.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you. I must have somehow missed this article even though I searched...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the documentation mentioned by Jimmy in comment, I tested in my VS2022 and it worked well.Firstly, nesting partial classes work for both  `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and the rest of the projects (Microsoft.NET.Sdk) .You should check `File nesting options` in solution explorer.

[image]

Here’re several methods to nest files.

1 when you select `Default`, if no settings exist for a given project type, then no files in the project are nested. You should create project-specific settings through the right-click menu (context menu) of the project console App (Microsoft.NET.Sdk).And use `pathSegment` to set the rules:
 For example

```
"pathSegment": {
        "add": {
          ".*": [
            ".cs",
          ]
        }
      }
```

RESULT

[image]

pathSegment: Use this type of rule to nest Catelog.Paged.cs under Catelog.cs

2 when you select `Web`: This option applies the Web file nesting behavior to all the projects in the current solution.

3 customize file nesting for a solution. Select `Add Custom Setting` in solution explorer. You can add as many custom file nesting settings as you like. It’s similar to method 1.

Answer (score 1):

This still does not work here...

I have a .Net 4.8 Class Libray and no partial .cs class gets nested under its parent.

I have tried all you wrote above but nothing does work.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Did you found a solution?

Comment: You can do it manually by editing the project file:


  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Child.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Parent.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>